# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in index.php line 100

Tags: php, html

Мой код:

```
<?php 
          // вся процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в ней хранятся    данные пользователя, пока он находится на сайте. Очень важно запустить их в    самом начале странички!!!
          session_start();          
include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и    все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь           
if    (!empty($_SESSION['login']) and !empty($_SESSION['password']))
            {
            //если существует логин и пароль в сессиях, то проверяем их и    извлекаем аватар

            $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
            $password    = $_SESSION['password'];
            $result    = mysql_query("SELECT id,avatar FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND    password='$password'",$db); 
            $myrow    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            //извлекаем нужные данные о пользователе
            }
            ?>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Главная    страница</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h2>Главная    страница</h2>          

<?php
            if    (!isset($myrow['avatar']) or $myrow['avatar']=='') {

            //проверяем, не извлечены ли данные пользователя из базы. Если    нет, то он не вошел, либо пароль в сессии неверный. Выводим окно для входа.    Но мы не будем его выводить для вошедших, им оно уже не нужно.
print    <<<HERE
            <form    action="testreg.php" method="post">
            <!-- testreg.php - это адрес обработчика. То есть, после нажатия на кнопку    "Войти", данные из полей отправятся на страничку testreg.php методом "post"  -->
              <p>
                <label>Ваш логин:<br></label>
                <input    name="login" type="text" size="15"    maxlength="15"
HERE;

            if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) //есть    ли переменная с логином в COOKIE. Должна быть,    если пользователь при предыдущем входе нажал на чекбокс "Запомнить    меня" 
            {
            //если да, то вставляем в форму ее значение. При этом    пользователю отображается, что его логин уже вписан в нужную графу
            echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE['login'].'">';
            }          


print <<<HERE
              </p>
            <!-- В текстовое поле (name="login" type="text") пользователь вводит свой    логин -->  
              <p>
                <label>Ваш пароль:<br></label>
                <input    name="password" type="password" size="15"    maxlength="15"
HERE;


            if (isset($_COOKIE['password']))//есть    ли переменная с паролем в COOKIE. Должна быть,    если пользователь при предыдущем входе нажал на чекбокс "Запомнить    меня" 
            {
            //если да, то вставляем в форму ее значение. При этом пользователю    отображается, что его пароль уже вписан в нужную графу
            echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE['password'].'">';
            }


print    <<<HERE
              </p>
            <!-- В поле для паролей (name="password"    type="password") пользователь вводит свой пароль -->  
              <p>
                <input name="save" type="checkbox"    value='1'> Запомнить меня.
              </p>          
<p>
            <input    type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
            <!-- Кнопочка (type="submit") отправляет данные на страничку testreg.php     --> 
            <br>

            <!-- ссылка на регистрацию, ведь как-то же должны гости    туда попадать  --> 
            <a    href="reg.php">Зарегистрироваться</a> 
            </p></form>
            <br>
            Вы    вошли на сайт, как гость<br><a    href='#'>Эта    ссылка доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям</a>
HERE;
            }          
else 
            {
            //при удачном входе пользователю выдается все, что расположено    ниже между звездочками.
            //************************************************************************************          

print <<<HERE

<!-- Между оператором     "print <<<HERE" выводится html код с нужными    переменными из php -->
            Вы    вошли на сайт, как $_SESSION[login] (<a    href='exit.php'>выход</a>)<br>
            <!-- выше ссылка на выход из аккаунта -->          
<a    href='http://tvpavlovsk.sk6.ru/'>Эта    ссылка доступна только зарегистрированным пользователям</a><br>

            Ваш    аватар:<br>
            <img    alt='$_SESSION[login]' src='$myrow[avatar]'> 
            <!-- Выше отображается аватар. Его адрес содержит    переменная $myrow[avatar] -->          
<!-- Именно здесь можно добавлять формы для отправки    комментариев и прочего... -->          
HERE;          

//************************************************************************************
            //при удачном входе пользователю выдается все, что расположено    ВЫШЕ между звездочками.
            }
?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Как исправить на линии 100 она последняя ?

Comment: Ошибка у вас где-то выше по тексту. Незакрытая кавычка, фигурная скобка, тег, запяточка, и т.д.

Comment: @Аол выше по тексту программы, вероятно, не хватает точки с запятой.

Comment: Но вот какую фигурную скобку поставить ? и куда я новичок в php

Comment: кто ж вам скажет, не видя код целиком?

Comment: Щяс поставлю тогда целиком

Comment: Сразу могу сказать я делал исправления в этом коде так как его кривовато немного написали

Comment: какое-то весьма сомнительное использование heredoc в коде у вас.

Comment: Он выдавал ошибку, а теперь нет по этому я думаю что он уже нормально работает

Comment: @Аол у вас, во первых, не правильное форматирование html-кода `пробелы там, где их быть не должно`, и во вторых у тегов input нет закрывающих угловых скобок ">".

Comment: там еще проблемы с `$_SESSION[login]`, `$myrow[avatar]`, ошибки могут не показываться но пишутся в лог

Comment: @Эдуард корректнее сказать, скобок может не быть. Они там в if-е добавляются.

Comment: Но как их исправить ? Там же они должно быть корректно работают

Comment: @teran ну в if-е же добавляются инпуты, и если они добавляются, то у них у всех нет закрывающей угловой скобки. Не? )

Comment: @Аол почитайте про html-синтаксис, как пишутся html-теги.

Comment: @Эдуард смотрите дальше по тексту есть `if (.. login .. )` там выводится `value=".." >` для этих инпутов. Вопрос в том, что он не всегда выполняется :)

Comment: @teran да уж, железная логика у кого-то ))

Comment: Но в принципе это не всю проблему решило так как еще 2 ошибки пока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас беда вот тут

```
<!-- Именно здесь можно добавлять формы для отправки    комментариев и прочего... -->          
HERE;          <---Вот тут кончается строка
```

Удалите все пробелы после `HERE;`

Документация нам говорит, что

> Очень важно отметить, что строка с закрывающим идентификатором не
>   должна содержать других символов, за исключением точки с запятой (;).
>   Это означает, что идентификатор не должен вводиться с отступом и что
>   не может быть никаких пробелов или знаков табуляции до или после точки
>   с запятой.

Comment: Помогло спасибо